# Convert Bangla written in Roman script to its phonetic equivalent in Bangla using Python

Tags: python, avro

I got a python package called **PyAvroPhonetic** and installed it.

```
>>> from pyavrophonetic import avro
```

After running the above script I got the following error -

> ImportError: No module named utils

But after running the following script

```
>>> import pyavrophonetic
```

there is no error. Here is the conversion code

```
>>> from pyavrophonetic import avro
>>> avro.parse('aami banglay gaan gai')
```

I have to use avro to call parse function. What should I do. I am using python 2.7.10. Thanks in advance.

pyAvroPhonetic: https://github.com/TrendBreaker/pyAvroPhonetic

Comment: Try printing the output of `parse` e.g. `print(avro.parse('aami banglay gaan gai'))`

Comment: It shows **NameError: name 'avro' is not defined** @shahkalpesh

Comment: The installers for this package seem to be broken - the 0.1.2 & 0.1.3 installers don't install the `utils.py` submodule; 0.1.1 does install it,  but doesn't install `resources/avrodict.json`.  You might be able to get it working by cloning directly from github.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am currently using Python 3 and I can share the way I use Avro Phonetic. I am using modified python 3 compatible "pyAvroPhonetic" library locally with my scripts. You can get the structure at - "https://github.com/improlabs/Banglish-Sentiment-Analysis/tree/master/python3"